# What is in an oAuth 2 token

Tags: oauth-2.0

I am not a programmer (more of a scripter) but wondered if someone could clear up the following for me please as I am learning out oAuth2

If you have a separate authentication server (e.g. google, facebook etc) and a separate resource server (some other site entirely)

when the 'client application' presents the 'access token' to the resource server (to get access to the users data). How does the resource server know it can trust the access token?

In other words is the access token x509 signed and converted to base64 or something like that so when the resource server receives the token it can convert back to json/xml or what ever format it is in then check the signature?

if so that would require the resource server to trust the authentication server in advanced of the access token being presented

I would be grateful if someone could clear this up for me please

Thank you

__CAshtones

Answer (score 0):

In this case, instead of access token, authorization code is used.

This is happening when a Facebook log in is clicked on an XYZ website.

1. XYZ website redirects to Facebook login page together with an XYZclientID(XYZ should be already registered under Facebook as a developer)
2. Facebook identifies that XYZ(using XYZclientID) wants to authenticate ABC person
3. ABC person log in to facebook.
4. Facebook issues an authorisation code(for ABC+XYZ combination) and redirects back to XYZ website.
5. XYZ uses this authorisation code + XYZclientID + XYZclientSecret to get a bearer token
6. Facebook validates the secret and issues a bearer token(linked to ABC person)
7. XYZ uses this bearer token to retrieve details of ABC person. (It cannot be used to retrieve data of DEG person)
8. Facebook give the email & other personal details of ABC to XYZ and XYZ shows that ABC is logged in.

More elaborated here :
https://www.scienceabc.com/innovation/oauth-how-does-login-with-facebook-google-work.html

Comment: Thanks very much for the reply